# Cast count(*) to two-digits string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count the number of records from a table and convert it to 2 digits string in SQL Server. For example:

```
|id|something|
|1 |      abc|
|2 |      def|
```

I want to have the result as '02'.

Please help me with a solution, Thanks.

Comment: Do the formatting required in the presentation layer

Comment: Please show us your attempt

Comment: What is the output if there are more than 99 rows?

Comment: it's just the number of student in a class, so it's always less than that big, friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `Format()` function in SQL Server you can format a number into a digit: e.g.
when you use `FORMAT(<Column_Name>, 'D2')` you can have numbers in two-digit form.

```
SELECT FORMAT(Id, 'D2'),*
FROM Test_Table
```